# Using the contents of an array outside a function

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a possibility to use the contents of an array in another function? For example, I have the following code:

```
var locations = [];

function values() {
 var values = ['test1','test1']
 for (i in values) {
   locations.push(values[i]);
 }
}

Logger.log(locations)
```

Now it logs nothing, but if I place the logger in the function, it returns the contents of the array.

Answer (score 2):

call function values();  like this

```
var locations = [];
values();

function values() {
 var values = ['test1','test1'];
 for (i in values) {
   locations.push(values[i]);
 }
}

Logger.log(locations);
```